# Spatie UrlSigner in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried and searched everything I could think of and I can not make Spatie UrlSigner work under Laravel.

Basically I have followed the step by step installation guide on his page.

Installed with composer.

Added the provider and facade in config/app.php:

```
    'providers' => [
    Spatie\UrlSigner\Laravel\UrlSignerServiceProvider::class,

],
'aliases' => [

    'UrlSigner' => Spatie\UrlSigner\Laravel\UrlSignerFacade::class,

],
```

Then in my controller I included the facade using the alias:

```
use UrlSigner;
```

And tried to used it in some function:

```
public function publicShow() {
    $url=UrlSigner::sign('http://example.com', 30);
    return $url;
}
```

This gives me a fatal error:

```
Class 'UrlSigner' not found
```

I have tried different methods, even including the class itself which returned a different error about not being allowed to call the method statically. All in all I feel like I've no solution left.

I think this is something trivial that I'm missing but being quite a beginner with Laravel I can't for the life of me find out what it is.

Cheers!

Comment: Call facade as `\UrlSigner::sign` or import facade like `use Spatie\UrlSigner\Laravel\UrlSignerFacade as UrlSigner`.

Comment: But best way is injecting `Spatie\UrlSigner\Laravel\UrlSigner` service.

Comment: @Vlad.i have installed now and its working fine for me .can you publish using following command php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\UrlSigner\Laravel\UrlSignerServiceProvider"

Comment: @maximkou:
Using \UrlSigner::sign didn't change anything.

However, including the full facade path as UrlSigner made it load but returned the error:

Class url-signer does not exist

I suspect it has something to do witht the package itself though it's likely I'm wrong.

Comment: @iCoders:

Yes, I got a "Publishing complete" success message. I think I did that before as well.

Comment: @Vlad, try to move your provider in config from top to down (to package service providers). `Class url-signer does not exist` error say about wrong registered provider.

Comment: then it should work fine.i have tested it

Comment: @maximkou: It was already last one in the list of package service providers. Moved it a bit from one section to the other with no impact.

Comment: @iCoders: Yeah, it looks like it should be working to me too, no idea what I'm missing. I'm close to doing a fresh laravel install just to try it there.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I just tried installing on a different laravel instance I had around and in a matter of 2 minutes it worked like a charm.

Might have something to do either with my app or my controller or my something. I will do a bit of experimenting and see what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was the correct way to load the package. After trying to install it on a different instance of Laravel and having everything work like a charm I did a bunch of comparing between those two.

Not sure why the very same facade worked on one instance and not on another despite using the exact same code on my end.

Solved it by deleting everything except .gitignore from the bootstrap/cache/ folder as suggested to a similar problem [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-cant-get-facade-to-work).

Thanks to everyone who helped!